# Match null of non-string field in Hibernate Search query

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am trying to implement a query for the following logic:

> Match results where ***endDate*** is above ***now*** OR ***endDate*** is not present (i.e. null)

So far, I am able to do the first part as following:

```
dateQuery = queryBuilder.range()
                        .onField("endDate")
                        .above(LocalDateTime.now())
                        .createQuery();
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out the second part. I have tried this (and failed):

```
queryBuilder.bool()
            .must(dateQuery)
            .should(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("endDate")
                                .matching("").createQuery())
            .createQuery();
```

Is there any elegant way of checking if a non-string field is Null in Hibernate Search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default empty/null values are not indexed, thus looking for an empty/null value will not return any result.

With Hibernate Search 6 and above, consider the [`exists()` predicate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-predicate-exists) predicate, which you can negate to find documents where a given field does not exist (has no value).

Hibernate Search 6.0 / 6.1:

```
List<Book> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
        .where( f -> f.bool().mustNot( f.exists().field( "endDate" ) ) )
        .fetchHits( 20 );
```

Or a simpler syntax with the upcoming release of Hibernate Search 6.2:

```
List<Book> hits = searchSession.search( Book.class )
        .where( f -> f.not( f.exists().field( "endDate" ) ) )
        .fetchHits( 20 );
```

Note however that, as a purely negative query, this won't perform well.

For larger indexes, if you want decent performance, consider indexing null as a non-null value. See [`@GenericField(indexNullAs = ...)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-directfieldmapping-indexnullas) (also available on other `@*Field` annotations).

Basically you'll annotate your property with something like `@GenericField(indexNullAs = "9999-12-31T23:59:59.999")`, then you'll create a query looking for the value `LocalDateTime.parse("9999-12-31T23:59:59.999")`, and Hibernate Search will return all documents that had a `null` value when indexed.

---

Old answer for Hibernate Search 5:

You should use `@Field(indexNullAs = "...")` in your mapping. In your case you should set `indexNullAs` to something like `9999-12-31T23:59:59.999` (last milisecond of the last day of year 9999).

See [the documentation about Field.indexNullAs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#field-annotation-indexNullAs) for more information.

Comment: I managed to circumvent the issue by playing with the logic a little bit like this:

`queryBuilder.bool().must(queryBuilder.range().onField("endDate").below(LocalDateTime.now()).createQuery()).not().createQuery();`

However, your answer correctly solves the issue without any workarounds. Thank you very much!